# Is there an elegant way to assert that one particular element goes before another one in a list?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have some ordering and after the ordering has been applied I want to assert in my unit test that one particular element goes before another one.

The ordering looks like approximately:

```
MyItems.OrderBy(x => x.Type)
.ThenBy(x => (x.Unlimited == true) ? 0 : 1)
```

`MyItems` is a collection of objects. It does not matter what they are. The matter is each of them has `Unlimited` `bool` field and I use the field in my second sorting. Let's make a quick example of them:

```
var MyItems = new List<MyItem>()
{
  new MyItem() 
  {
    Type = ServiceTypes.Internet
    Unlimited = false,
    Id = 1
  },
  new MyItem() 
  {
    Type = ServiceTypes.Internet
    Unlimited = true,
    Id = 2
  },
  new MyItem() 
  {
    Type = ServiceTypes.SMS
    Unlimited = false,
    Id = 3
  },
}
```

So, the result of the sorting is supposed that `MyItem` with `Id` 2 goes before the item with `Id` 1.

How can I assert it in unit tests? I invented something with loop `foreach` and `boolean` flags, but it's ugly.

```
 [Fact]
public MyTest()
{
    // act
    var result = _myService.GetMyItems(...);

    // assert
    Assert. // do here something more smart and elegant than foreach logic

}
```

Do you have better ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure did I misunderstanding.  There is my thought ```Assert.Greater( list.FinIndex(x => id == 2), list.FinIndex(x => id == 1) )```

Comment: It is always allowed to write private helper methods in UnitTests, something like `Assert.IsTrue(IdsAreSubsequent(MyItems, 2, 1));`.

Comment: C# 11 [List patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#list-patterns)?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using *zip* method on linq:

```cs
var isSorted = MyItems
    // check indexes of items of the same type
    // since this property is a main sorting key
    .GroupBy(item => item.Type)
    .All(g => {
            var limited = g.Where(i => !i.Unlimited);
            var unlimited = g.Where(i => i.Unlimited);

            // pair all unlimited with limited items
            return unlimited.Zip(limited)
                // and assume that all indexes of unlimited items
                // are smaller than limited ones in the original list
                .All(zip => MyItems.FindIndex(i => i.Id == zip.First.Id) < MyItems.FindIndex(i => i.Id == zip.Second.Id));
    });

Assert.True(isSorted);
```